# Writing a function in R to solve Plank's equation

Tags: r, function, equation

I am trying to write my first function in R to calculate emittance using Plank's function for different temperatures. I can do it manually as below for temperatures from 200 to 310 K.

```
pi <- 3.141593
h <- 6.626068963e-34
c <- 2.99792458e+8
lambda <- 4 * 1e-6
k <- 1.38e-23
t <- c (200:310)
a <- (2*pi*(c^2)*h)/(lambda^5)
b <- exp((h*c)/(lambda*k*t))
B <- a * (1/(b-1))
```

Where B is the vector of values I want.

Now here is an effort to write a function in R:

```
P_function <- function(t, pi = 3.141593, h = 6.626068963e-34, c = 2.99792458e+8,
             lambda = 4 * 1e-6, k = 1.38e-2) {
         ((2*pi*(c^2)*h)/(lambda^5)) *((1/(exp((h*c)/(lambda*k*t))-1)))
}
```

Now for different values of t (200-300K), how do I implement this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems. First, `pi` is already a defined constant at better precision than you are using.

```
> rm(pi)  # remove your copy
> pi
[1] 3.141593   # default for console printing is  only 8 digits
> print(pi, digits=18)
[1] 3.14159265358979312  # but there is more "depth" to be had
```

Second, it makes no sense to put scientific constants in the parameter list. Since they're constant they can be defined in the body. Parameter lists are for items that might vary from situation to situation.

```
newPfun <- function(t) { h <- 6.626068963e-34
   c <- 2.99792458e+8
   lambda <- 4 * 1e-6
   k <- 1.38e-23
   a <- (2*pi*(c^2)*h)/(lambda^5)   #pi is already defined
   b <- exp((h*c)/(lambda*k*t))
   B <- a * (1/(b-1))
 return(B) }
```

This is just your original code "packaged" to accept a vector of temperatures. (And I'm pretty sure that's not the right spelling the scientist's name.)

Not sure where your second function is flawed. Perhaps a mismatched parenthesis. After trying to duplicate the results with a single expression and failing multiple times, I'm now wondering if it's really a problem with numerical overflow (or underflow).

Comment: It's a bad idea to redefine `c`, one of the most fundamental functions in R, as the speed of light. Perhaps `C` instead.

Comment: Heh, while I certainly agree that `c` is not a great name for a data object, you are NOT "redefining `c`", since data objects and functions are stored in different lists. Furthermore, `C` is also a function name, so that would not be particularly wise if you have decided to follow your own sensible advice to avoid using existing function names for data objects. Do you likewise be remind other users when they use `df` as a name for a data object. It's also a function name.

Comment: Actually, yes, I tell people to avoid using `df` as a variable for the same reason. But I was not aware of the function `C`, since that's a less well known one than `c`.

Comment: @Brian So you should not be telling people that creating a data-object is redefining an existing function. Only when an existing function name is assigned to a new function object will there be masking. The main downside to a data assignment will be that code becomes more difficult to read and error messages become confusing. (You're going to be a really busy guy with commenting if you attempt to correct everyone who uses `df` as a data-object name. I used to do that but now generally just use "dfrm" in my work.)